# What is the average time it takes for a question to be answered?

Tags: discussion

What is the average time it takes for a question to be answered? I would write a program for this question myself, but I do not know how to program:
http://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/new

Comment: Why didn't I get reputation points for this question being upvoted?

Comment: Because it's in meta, and your rep comes from the main.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/edit/276810) if you're curious.

From that, the average wait for the first answer for questions that have been answered is 1 day, 18 hours, and 17 minutes.